# How to print out lines after a certain string in java?

Tags: java

I am trying to print out all the lines in a certain chapter. This is what I have so far.. a main method which takes in user input of a book name and chapter number which then splits the string to store them in separate data types for the program to use and then calls the method.

```
    private static List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception{

      //findDetailsByWordSearch();
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Please enter the name of the file you wish to search and the chapter    number");
      String input = scnr.nextLine();
      String parts[] = input.split(" ");
      int chapterNumber = Integer.parseInt(parts[parts.length -1]);
        String bookName = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.length - 1; i++){
            bookName += parts[i];
        }
      getChapter(bookName, chapterNumber);

    }
```

Next is the method which uses the input from the user to find the book you are looking for, stores the text into an arraylist and also gets the chapter number however, the current code only prints out that one line but I need it to print out all the lines after the "CHAPTER "+chapterNumber point up until a blank space occurs which indicates the end of the chapter.

```
   public static void getChapter(String bookName, int chapterNumber) throws Exception{  
      String textExtension = ".txt";
      String fileContent;

      try {
          BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(bookName +textExtension));
            while ((fileContent = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                list.add(fileContent);    
            }               
            for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
                String lines = list.get(i);
                if(lines.equals("CHAPTER "+chapterNumber)){
                    System.out.println(lines);      
                }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

The chapters follow the following format:
CHAPTER 1 (Text on several lines) followed by a blanked space CHAPTER 2 (Text on several lines) and so on... So the question is how do I print out the text after and in the chapter is found, for example, if the user was searching for say 'Harry 4', the system would find the book harry and read the text into an arraylist then find CHAPTER 4 and print out the text in that chapter until CHAPTER 5. 
Thanks!

Comment: It's basically a tiny state machine. You're not printing lines until you see `CHAPTER n`. You're printing lines until you see the next `CHAPTER n`.

Comment: It seems that you need to *iterate* over all the lines *while* the given line is not `chapterNumber + 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you don't need to read the lines into a `List` at all. If the whole task is just to print them, then you need to read each line, decide if this line is a line you want to print according to your conditions, and if so, just print it.

This will save you a lot of memory, especially if the books are long.

So how do you do that? You know that you want to print the lines starting with `CHAPTER n`, and ending with a blank line. So when you read a line, you ask yourself: "Is this line part of the chapter"? Obviously, if you have not read the line `CHAPTER n` yet, then it is not. After you have read the `CHAPTER n`, the answer is yes - unless your line is empty.

So you keep a flag that says which *state* you are in: having read `CHAPTER n` or not. At first, the flag is false.

For each line you read:

- If you are in the state of "didn't read that line yet":

  - Check if the current line is `CHAPTER n`. If so, change the flag.
- If you are in the state of "read that line":

  - Check if the current line is blank. If so, close the file and return.
  - If not, print the line.

This is known as a "state machine", where you get an input, one at a time, but your behavior is different depending on your state, and that behavior can include moving from one state to another state.

```
  boolean inChapter = false;

  try (
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(bookName +textExtension));
  ) {
      while ((fileContent = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            if ( inChapter ) {
                if ( fileContent.isEmpty() ) {
                    return;
                }
                System.out.println( fileContent );
            } else {
                if ( fileContent.equals("CHAPTER "+chapterNumber ) {
                   inChapter = true;
                   System.out.println( fileContent );
                }
            }
      }               
  } catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Note that I used "try with resources" which will close your file automatically.

Comment: Thank you very much it works however, I need to make use of any collection, any way to add that in?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Where do you need to use a collection? Perhaps some other part of the assignment would benefit from a collection. Maybe you should add the complete definition of your assignment to your original question.

Comment: I see what you mean, it specified to make use of collections either lists or maps however, if that's not possible in this case I'll just leave it out :/.. I tried to use a enhanced for, store the book in a string and then retry this code but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you maintain a map with key as chapterNumber, and array containing start and end line number of chapter like below:

```
 int chapterStart = 1;
 int chaperNumber = 1;
 int lineNumber = 0;
 while ((fileContent = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    list.add(fileContent);
    lineNumber ++;
    if (fileContent.startsWith("Chapter") && lineNumber != 1) {
        map.put(chaperNumber++, new int[] {chapterStart, lineNumber - 1});
        chapterStart = lineNumber;
    }
 }  
 map.put(chaperNumber, new int[] {chapterStart, lineNumber - 1});//last chapter ends
```

And then given chapterNumber, you could read map with key as chapterId, you will get start and end line and you could just get lines by position from list.

Comment: Thanks for the response but, this for some reason gives all the chapter numbers in the document and not the one I'm searching for. unless I'm writing it out incorrectly.